# C++ Events creating and handling

Tags: c++

i would like to create a C++ Projects which includes events and their handlers.
Can u Please tell me How can i Create and handle events in C++?

Thnx for the support...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean plain ANSI C++? If yes, have a look at [boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/signals2.html).